# SOAP web service not working for EJB calls

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, ejb

I am trying to create a SOAP based web service, which will call stateless EJB in other project. My configuration is Server: WAS 8.5,IDE: RAD 8.5,Java 1.6, EJB 3.1, and SOAP 1.1. When I write a simple addition method it properly create Web Service, WSDL and i can access the Web Service. But When i add another method which calls EJB it wont allows me to create service and WSDL, it throws below error popup :

Errors occurred during wsgen.

```
error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported
warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
Note:   ap round: 1
Problem encountered during annotation processing; 
see stacktrace below for more information.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalType(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.methodsAreLegal(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalImplementation(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.shouldProcessWebService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitClassDeclaration(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.ClassDeclarationImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.buildModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.main.AptJavaCompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jws22.v85.command.AbstractWsGenCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.command.WsGenCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    ....
```

This is my code which works fine

```
public class Operations {
    public int addition(int x, int y){
        return x+y;
    }
    public String Greetings(String name){
        return "happy birthday"+name;
    }
}
```

when i add

```
@EJB
    private transient StatusEJBBeanLocal statusEJBBeanLocal;
    public Product StatusFromProductId(int ProdutoID) {
        Product produto = null;
        produto = this.statusEJBBeanLocal.StatusFromProductId(ProdutoID);
        return produto;
    }
```

It shows error. Please help me out here with some tutorial link or tell me whats wrong with my code, how to call EJB from Web services. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you use transient modifier in statusEJBBeanLocal? Try remove it.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller tried removing transient modifier, still same issue.

Comment: You must declare your webservice as stateless ejb too for it to access another EJB

Comment: @maress then my webservices class will become EJB itself, and it will be like calling ejb from ejb.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for your answers. I solved it by using annotations, it will not generate physical WSDL at separate location but it will create Web Service in Services section of your web project, just right click on it and Show> WSDL Inteface to see WSDL also you can test it from their. Annotations used: Created Interface manually and then Implementation.
`@WebService(name = "StatusSEI", targetNamespace = "http://ws.status.mycomp.corp")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use = Use.LITERAL)
@WebMethod`